# Cannot implicitly convert type - c# tuples

Tags: c#

So, the problem is: I've got a function, which takes two numbers, which user wrote in console, I want to return these two numbers, so I decide to use Tuples.

```
static int InputedData()
{
    int data1, data2;
    Console.WriteLine("Enter first number:");
    data1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("Enter second number:");
    data2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    int result = (data1, data2); //Tuples, also tried with var
    return result;
}
```

Comment: because `int` is not a `Tuple`

Comment: `int` isn't a tuple of two ints. It's just one int. `static (int x, int y) InputedData() { /*...*/ return (data1, data2); }`. Also, "inputted" has two Ts, if it's a word.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a misunderstanding of how the return type works in the method signature and return values.

```
static (int, int) InputedData()
{
    int data1, data2;
    Console.WriteLine("Enter first number:");
    data1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("Enter second number:");
    data2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine())

    return (data1, data2); 
}
```

Notice the implicit definition of the tuple `(int, int)` in the method signature and in defining the return value. You can't do `int data = (data1, data2)` because you are trying to cram a tuple into an `int`.

You can also name the tuples if you want:

```
static (int a, int b) InputedData()
{
    //...
}
```

Which makes it more apparent what they mean when using those values in another method. If you don't name them, the default name is `Item1` and `Item2`.